# Deployed Blazor server to localhost, Default Login page (cshtml) Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have deployed a Blazor server site to localhost/store and make required adjustments, The web site works but there is a problem with its Login.cshtml page, Its GetAsync method works good, and it has the expected web address:
http://localhost/store/identity/account/login/?lang=en&returnUrl=%2fstore%2fcoronavirus
But when I enter my user name and password it says: "Sorry, there's nothing at this address.", and shows the same address when it first loaded:
http://localhost/store/identity/account/login/?lang=en&returnUrl=%2fstore%2fcoronavirus
The code for Login page is:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
    ...

    public LoginModel(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, ...)            
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        ...
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; } = null;
    [BindProperty]
    public string Lang { get; set; } = "fa";

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]           
        [MaxLength(256)]
        public string User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
   
    public async Task OnGetAsync([FromQuery]string returnUrl = null, [FromQuery] string lang = "en")
    {                         
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        Lang = lang;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true                
            AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "User not found.");
                GetLanguageValues(Lang);
                return Page(); // <= I think problem is here
            }
            if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
            {                    
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You didn't confirmed your Email.");
                GetLanguageValues(Lang);
                return Page();
            }
            if (!user.IsApproved)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                GetLanguageValues(Lang);
                return Page();
            }
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.User, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {                    
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");                    
                user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                return LocalRedirect(ReturnUrl);
            }                
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {                    
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You are Locked Out.");
                GetLanguageValues(Lang);
                return Page();
            }               
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                GetLanguageValues(Lang);
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        GetLanguageValues(Lang);
        return Page();
    }
```

since the browser shows the same address after pressing login, I think a "return Page()" is executed and then OnPostAsync() should execute but it is not found! if it is a succcess the browser should redirect to "returnUrl" and show that url, I also render Model properties in the view. why I get this error? all parts work except cshtml (it works when I run the project in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed all src and href in shared\_Layout.cshtml, so that they are not begin with '/' slash and now it works.

Edit:

After Try and error I realized that src and hrefs in the cshtml files should begin with "~/" and in the blazor main app should be like this: "css/aaa/bbb/c.css" so don't begin with a slash.
For the original problem, It seems return Redirect(ReturnUrl) is correct and in edge, when I press login button, the correct url appears for a second in address bar and then comes back to original page (Login page).

It seems the browser can not read the set auth cookie, and the authentication if statement in the target page, redirects back to Login page.

I tried this in Edge Canary and Chrome and in Firefox and in these browsers redirection from login page to target page worked correctly with Auth cookie set. But in edge there is a problem.